# How to only add something to a string if it doesn't contain it?

Tags: java

I am making a Lipogram program where any words with the banned letter are printed, however, the words are sometimes printed twice. How do I get it to not repeat the words?

Here is my code:

```
public String allWordsWith(char letter) {

String str = "";
String word = "";

    s = s.replace(".", " ");
    s = s.replace(",", " ");
    s = s.replace("?", " ");
    s = s.replace("!", " ");
    s = " " + s + " ";

    for (int i = 0; i <= s.lastIndexOf(letter); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == letter) {
            if (str.contains(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ", i), s.lastIndexOf(" ", i) + 1) + '\n') == true) {

            } else {
                word += s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ", i), s.indexOf(" ", i)) + '\n';
                str += word;
            }
        }
    }

    return str;

}
```

Comment: What is `s`? And a method (especially in this context) should have a comment that documents its intended behaviour. Further, this looks quite ugly and inefficient, you should use a HashSet

Comment: Copy values to Set<>, then compare your words with your set items. It costs performance, but it works if you need.

Comment: @solvator the performance cost is not so high as you may think...

Comment: it depends from your data set (letters you wanted to compare)

Comment: @user3273793 Use Sets as I suggested in my answer. The answer seems to be ticked the folks here the wrong way apparently. I am not interested in reinventing the wheel over and over so I've deleted it. Good luck.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo see here: [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862), points 6 and 12, then points 10 and 11 and compare it with the current state of your deleted answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 6 doesn't apply here, its for internal links (did you read the answer?) and neither does 12. I didn't just say: "See here...bye". I gave the reason on why he should use it. The guidelines don't say "hold the OP's hands and implement it". EDIT: Also 10 and 11 are irrelevant. Sets are part of Java. The OP is asking about a fix in Java...

Comment: @NicolásCarlo you just posted *use foo because it may solve your problem* but didn't explain how and where to apply it. For future answers improve their content: explain **why** applies to this case based on the current problem and provide an example (you could use OP's code to provide the example, if you cannot maybe you need to review your answer).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza (My last comment on this by the way, not really interested in taking over the OP's thread.) The question specifically asks, "How to only add something to a string if it doesn't contain it", and then the OP says "however, the words are sometimes printed twice. How do I get it to not repeat the words?" My answer said, "Use Sets [with a link] because they make sure you don't have duplicates." Ergo, they solve your problem. Not MAY solve but DO solve. I could use OP's code to provide an example. I could also do the work for the OP. But I think I'd rather not.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo you could use the `Set` to save whatever may be repeating, but what's that thing to *save*, and where? And no, your answer doesn't address the whole problem, but just a part of it... And the way you posted the answer, is a bare comment.

Answer (score 0):

Important clarification:  Is the function run with the letter chosen as "o" on the string "hello hi hello howdy" meant to return "hello hello howdy" or "hello howdy".  I.e., if the word appears twice, do you want to print it twice, or do you only want to print it once regardless of repetition?

If only once regardless of repetition, then you should be using a Set to store your data.

However, I think there's a chance you're instead dealing with an issue that when running the function with the letter chosen as "l" on that same string, "hello hi hello howdy", you are getting an output of "hello hello hello hello".  Correct?

The issue here is that you are checking every letter and not testing each *word*.  To fix this, I would use:

```
String[] words = s.split(" ");
```

to create an array of your words.  Test each value in that array to see if it contains the given letter using:

```
if(words[index].contains(letter)){
    str += " " + words[index];
}
```